# Visualization on Cluster for Mixed Data

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-analysis, data-visualization, euclidean-distance

So, i'm working with fuzzy clustering for Mixed data. Then i want to do Visualization for clustering result. 
Here is my data

```
> head(x)
x1 x2        x3       x4
A  C    8.461373 27.62996
B  C   10.962334 27.22474
A  C    9.452127 27.57246
B  D    8.196687 27.29332
A  D    8.961367 26.72793
B  C    8.009029 27.97227
```

i followed this step https://www.r-bloggers.com/clustering-mixed-data-types-in-r/

```
gower_dist <- daisy(x,
                 metric = "gower")
                 #type = list(logratio = 1))
tsne_obj <- Rtsne(gower_dist1, dims=2 ,is_distance = TRUE)
tsne_data = data.frame(tsne_obj1$Y, factor(g1$clusters))
colnames(tsne_data1)[3] = "cluster"


ggplot(aes(x = X1, y = X2), data = tsne_data1) +
geom_point(aes(color = cluster))
```

Based on the website, the first step has transformed the data using Gower distance (i guess), then applying R-tsne.

So My question is :
Is it good using Rtsne for mixed data (as Representative the points)? I have doubt, with Gower distance in the first step, its like force your categorical data to be numeric data.

But one thing that amazed me, my method always give a better result than a classic method based on the plot. so this is important for me to know better about this, can I use the plot as a tool to measure the goodness of clustering result? because based on the plot, it's not difficult to determine which method is better (by plotting clustering result), I give plot images below, I really impressed with it.

Classic Method

[image]

My Method

[image]

Comment: Possibly this is a question for cross-validated...However if by "better" results you mean tighter clusters. Then yes t-sne is designed to make  or find tight clusters. But it is not necessarily a good way to judge how tightly clustered your data actually is. Have a look here: https://distill.pub/2016/misread-tsne/ - especially point 2.

Comment: This isn't a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about the appropriate use of various statistical methods, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: my bad, thanks by the way for the article. @StephenHenderson

Comment: @Jackshephard Your question is not clear. I'm surprised it has survived without being closed. There is no way to compared methods since you have not explained what is your methods is. Both plots are the same expect for clustering, you haven't shown what clustering methods were used.